# Yiibooster - TbExtendedGridView

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, yii-booster

I am using YiiBooster extensions --> TbExtendedGridView --> The Grid/Chart switcher in my application. [Grid/Chart Switch](http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView/index.html#gridswitch)

So by default it displays the Grid view and we can select chart option too. Does anyone know how can I change it to chart as the default view when the page is loaded.

I was looking into TbExtendedGridView.php but did not find how to change that. I would really appreciate if you could help me on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They added this property in the chartOptions in the extension on request.

> .defaultView, which is a flag used to set the chart as the default view of the widget

[The Grid/Chart switcher](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView/index.html#gridswitch)

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box support for what you are asking but we can use JS to implement this functionality

When you create this TbExtendedGridView note down the class name or unique ID of your 'Chart' button and on page load put the following JS :-

```
$('.chart.btn').trigger('click'); //user ID or class names as selector in jQuery
```

This will trigger a click event on the chart button and you will get chart view by default.